# correct usage comma/ definition of clause

Tags: grammar, british-english

He felt that the close first person perspective leaves the reader "too uncritically accepting of her worldview", and **often leads reading and conversation about the novel towards supporting Jane.**

Is the comma just for clarity here & accurate? When the conjunction joins a dependent clause can the comma be optional for clarity or is this example wrong ?

Comment: Punctuation "rules" vary.  The comma was inserted there probably to give the reader a "mental breather".  Although it is grammatical, it is not a very well written sentence.  "leads reading ...  towards supporting" is not good.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the parse:

He felt ||that the close first-person perspective ||leaves the reader "too uncritically accepting of her worldview" ||and|| often leads the reading and conversation about the novel in a direction that supports Jane.

there are two complements:  leave the reader [etc.] + often leads to [etc].

They have equal weight structurally. Therefore, there should be no comma. There is a parallel structure.

As in: This leaves the reader wonder ||and|| often leads to confusion.

Same idea.